# to import data from a diff tab of same sheet and trying to display it using a multiple condition

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

```
if ( = importRange("1HZBAodV7IOu4j_S10CbhKZeBOgHHCAIzB-WJs79oj1M", "Part_Requirement!K") = "Confirmed" && = importRange("1HZBAodV7IOu4j_S10CbhKZeBOgHHCAIzB-WJs79oj1M", "Part_Requirement!AA") = "Pending") {
    console.log(ali)
}
```

trying to import data from a diff tab of same sheet and trying to display it using a multiple condition.But unable to obatin desired answers,please help,thnkx in advance. hOAL

Answer (score 0):

`IMPORTRANGE()` is used to import a range from a different spreadsheet. What you're looking for is `FILTER()`, see [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) for reference.